# Content type form template

Tags: forms, drupal-7

I would like a drupal form to be displayed only if the GET variable matches in a list of one time passwords. That is, a user will be emailed a URL to a drupal form that contains a one time password and if its a valid password they can submit to that drupal form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd moderate the one-time, seemingly random URLs, but you could create a content type with a password field that you denote, send the URL with that password to whoever you want to access it and insert this in the template:

example URL: mysite.com/form?key=1234567

```
if(isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['key'] == render($content['field_password'])) {
    //do whatever here
} else {
print 'You do not have access.';
}
```

If that doesn't cut it, look into the Log In One Time module which allows you to send one time login urls to your site, then terminate the account after a period of time.

http://drupal.org/project/login_one_time